# How to log messages to file in Quickfix C++

Tags: c++, quickfix

I looked at the Log.h file, it seems like I need to implement my own log class inherit from the interface to log messages to file
I am just wondering if there is any existing class to use to log messages to file, I know there is a ScreenLogFactory, but I am not printing them onto screen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly implement your own custom logger, but for a simple case there is already a  [`FIX::FileLogFactory`](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_file_log_factory.html) class that you can use to have simple file logger.

Also check the [logging configuration](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html#Logging) document.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you, I never noticed that, I thought that file log class should be in Log.h

Comment: one more question, in my configuration file I have FileLogPath=E:\...
But I am having error finding this key, what might be the problem?

Comment: @cynric4sure: what key, and where you think you should find it?

Comment: FileLogPath, when quickfix parse the configuration file, it said ConfigError.  I looked into the call stack found that it was looking for "FileLogPath", but the find(key) returns nothing while I do have "FileLogPath=E:\Path" in my configuration file.

Comment: @cynric4sure: Then you don't have it, or have it in the wrong place.

Comment: I have found out, need use "/" instead of "\" in path